# Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [256,2] and element 36 had shape [32,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working with fashion MNIST dataset and I want to build an Artificial Neural Network using custom layers created by my own:

Here is my preprocessing phase:

```
#ANN with fashion mnist data_set
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import Model

#Loading dataset and preprocessing:
(X_train,Y_train),(X_test,Y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

unique_labels = set(Y_train)

X_train = X_train/255 #because max value of pixel is 255
X_test = X_test/255 #because max value of pixel is 255

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,28*28)#flatten image from 28*28 to N*(28*28), second dimension - all the pixels of image
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,28*28)

Y_train = Y_train.reshape(Y_train.shape[0],1)
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(Y_test.shape[0],1)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))
dataset_train = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, Y_test))
dataset_test = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)
```

Here you can see, that I have preprocessed data so that they have 2-D shape(which suits better for ANN).
I know, that I could use CNN for the following task, but my goal is to practice with ANN.

And at the end I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-24b493b0dcc5> in <module>()
    102 
    103 for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
--> 104   for X,y in dataset_train:
    105     training(X,y)
    106 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [256,2] and element 36 had shape [32,2]. [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

But if I don't use `batch(64)` everything works perfeclty fine.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using some previously cached `tf.Dataset`. Because you have `train_dataset` and `test_dataset`, not `dataset`. I tested the following code and it will return a batch of size `64`.

```
#ANN with fashion mnist data_set
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import Model

#Loading dataset and preprocessing:
(X_train,Y_train),(X_test,Y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

unique_labels = set(Y_train)

X_train = X_train/255 #because max value of pixel is 255
X_test = X_test/255 #because max value of pixel is 255

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,28*28)#flatten image from 28*28 to N*(28*28), second dimension - all the pixels of image
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,28*28)

Y_train = Y_train.reshape(Y_train.shape[0],1)
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(Y_test.shape[0],1)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, Y_test))
dataset_test = dataset_test.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

# Checking if we are actually getting a batch of data of size 64

# Creating an iterator
iterator = dataset_test.make_one_shot_iterator()

# Getting one batch of data
bi,bl = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  e_bi = sess.run(bi)
  print(e_bi.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful method to batch that kind of dataset:

```py
    tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch
```

you can also get help from TF official documents:
[tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch)